# Redirect_to another page in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

In my application I have a set of entities. Now I want to build a search form on my start page that calls the action of controller a. If it finds more than one entitiy it shall show all the products if it finds exactly one product it should redirecto to another controller that loads the detailed information about the entity and shows it. In my first controller I do this by calling

```
if @entities.length==1
      redirect_to show_path(:id=>@entities[0].id)
    end
```

I would expect that now a new site is opened like /show?id=1234 but that does not happen. Instead the controller behind the entity path loads the detailed information of the entity but nothing is shown.

I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template entities/show with {:formats=>[:js, :"*/*"], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :erb, :builder], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths ..."):
```

How do I get the right page loaded, simply adding the show.js.erb to the entities folder makes the error disappear but the problem still remains that the show page is not shown.

EDIT:

```
 render :update do |page|
        page.redirect_to show_product_path(:id=>@entities[0].id)
      end
```

this works but why? what is the difference?

Comment: What is in your entities/show.js.erb file?

Comment: render :update do |page|
        page.redirect_to show_path(:id=>@entities[0].id)
      end
this works but why?

Comment: nothing I don't know what to fill in, also I want to have this working without javascript

Comment: Is this action being called by an AJAX request or by a full browser request?

Comment: The key word here is 'render'.  If you were just redirecting to show.js.erb, like your first example, you are literally just outputting a javascript file.  With the render block, you are telling rails that you want to redirect and then render the show.html file for the object.

Comment: Also, what's in your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to rederect straight to object. Rails is smart enough to create route for your object.

```
if @entities.length==1
  redirect_to @entities.first
end
```

Comment: `show_view` of what?  Rails will redirect you to `show` action of a `entity` controller (if it is defined as a resource)

Comment: If you pass an object to redirect_to, *and* you're using RESTful routing, Rails *will* redirect to the show page for that object

Answer (score 0):

I thnink

```
render :update do |page|
        page.redirect_to show_product_path(:id=>@entities[0].id)
end
```

code is looking for a show action in the same controller, where as

```
render :update do |page|
        page.redirect_to show_product_path(:id=>@entities[0].id)
 end
```

is redirecting to products/show in products controller. I think you dont have a 'show' action in 'entities' controller thats why you are getting

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template entities/show with {:formats=>[:js, :"*/*"], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :erb, :builder], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths ..."):
```

**With the default rails configuration it works as follows**

in your controller

```
class EntitiesController < ApplicationController

  def index

    #will display all the products
    **#you need to have a index.erb.html file as well**
    @products = <Your product getting logic here>

  end

  def show
    #display only one product
    #you need to have a show.erb.html 
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

So in you case you should redirect as

`show_product_path` with an id

and make sure you have show action defined in the controller

HTH

sameera